# как получить максимальный номер, если есть знак -?

Tags: mysql

У меня в базе есть записи

```
Department | document_nr
446191025  | 446191025-8
446191025  | 446191025-9
446191025  | 446191025-10
446191025  | 446191025-11
446191025  | 446191025-12
446191025  | 446191025-13
```

Как получить максимальное значение 446191025-13?

```
$local_conn->query("SELECT MAX(document_nr) as doc_nr FROM emails_sent WHERE Department = '{$department_search}'");
```

Мой вариант выдает 446191025-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поспешил с вопросом. Нашел такое решение

```
$local_conn->query("SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(document_nr, LOCATE('-', document_nr) + 1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS max_value FROM emails_sent WHERE Department = '{$department_search}'");
```